# X and Y names from a melted object for aes

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is one of those issues where you are not sure what you should be asking. What I am trying to do is to plot heat maps of different attraction repulsion values which are in a matrix form. For the plotting I am using a melted version of the matrix, `melted <- melt(ar_values)`, with the reshape library. I would like to be able to access the necessary x and y value for aes from the melted object, and not type it manually every time. However if I use the name from the melted object, then I get a "map" of one block, instead of a proper heat map between the elements.

The code below is working

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)

x = c(1, 2, 3, 4)
y = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4)
AR <- x %*% t(y)
AR
melted <- melt(AR)
melted
ggplot(melted, aes(X1, X2, fill=melted$value), environment()) +
    geom_tile() +
    scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", high = "red", mid = "white",
                         midpoint = median(melted$value), limit = c(min(melted$value), max(melted$value)),
                         name="AR value") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1,
                                     size = 9, hjust = 1)) +
    coord_fixed() +
    ggtitle(label = c('Heatmap representation of the Attraction Repulsion Matrix')) +
    xlab("X1") +
    ylab("X2")
```

the code below is not, where I quoted X1 and X2

```
library(ca)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)

x = c(1, 2, 3, 4)
y = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4)
AR <- x %*% t(y)
AR
melted <- melt(AR)
melted
ggplot(melted, aes("X1", "X2", fill=melted$value), environment()) +
    geom_tile() +
    scale_fill_gradient2(low = "blue", high = "red", mid = "white",
                         midpoint = median(melted$value), limit = c(min(melted$value), max(melted$value)),
                         name="AR value") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1,
                                     size = 9, hjust = 1)) +
    coord_fixed() +
    ggtitle(label = c('Heatmap representation of the Attraction Repulsion Matrix')) +
    xlab("X1") +
    ylab("X2")
```

Comment: 1) Remove `melted$` from `aes()`; 2) What is the purpose of `environment()` in the same `aes()`? Also remove it and try to see if it works; 3) Have you tried `get("X1")` and `get("X2")`?

Comment: This works: `ggplot(melted, aes(get("X1"), get("X2"), fill = value)) + etc`. In `help("get")` you will see that it searches for an object *by name* within the environment of `melted`.

Comment: Making use of the `.data` pronoun you could also do `ggplot(melted, aes(.data[["X1"]], .data[["X2"]], fill=value))`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas and @ stefan, thanks for the suggestions, these fixed the problem. If I were to plot n heatmaps from n melted objects, what would be the canonical way to do this in R? Names of the first two columns can vary from instance to instance.

Comment: Can you say how do you want the plots? Saved to files, or in a multiple plots grid, what?

Comment: @RuiBarradas Preferably multiple plots grid. No need to save them to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of arranging several plots in a grid with package `cowplot`.

First, define a function to plot the heatmap in the question, then call the function on the list of melted data.frames. And finally, plot the grid. Note that I had to break the plot title by inserting a newline `"\n"` character.

```
plot_fun <- function(data, low = "blue", high = "red", mid = "white"){
  x <- names(data)[1]
  y <- names(data)[2]
  value <- names(data)[3]
  ggplot(data, aes(.data[[x]], .data[[y]], fill = .data[[value]])) +
    geom_tile() +
    scale_fill_gradient2(low = low, high = high, mid = mid,
                         midpoint = median(data[[value]]), 
                         limit = range(data[[value]]),
                         name = "AR value") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1,
                                     size = 9, hjust = 1)) +
    coord_fixed() +
    ggtitle(label = c('Heatmap representation of the\n Attraction Repulsion Matrix')) +
    xlab(x) +
    ylab(y)
}

# put the plots in a list object with mget
df_list <- mget(ls(pattern = "^melted"))
plot_list <- lapply(df_list, plot_fun)

cowplot::plot_grid(plotlist = plot_list, nrow = 2)
```

[image]

**Data**

```
melted2 <- melted3 <- melted4 <- melted
names(melted2)[1:2] <- c("col1", "col2")
names(melted3)[1:2] <- c("x.col", "y.col")
names(melted4)[1:2] <- c("x_var", "y_var")
```